# Importing PDFs into Drupal as content types

Tags: files

I'm new to Drupal and I have a question.

Is there any way to import table data on PDFs into Drupal, creating them as events?

I don't believe there is but I want to double check.

Answer (score 5):

Not an easy task, I guess. [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) is a toolkit to detect and extract metadata and structured text from various documents, PDF included. Is used, for example, by Apache Solr to parse and index PDF (and other) documents.

You may use Apache Tika to parse PDF documents and get the data you want, then create what you need (a Content Type, an Event).

[Apache Solr Attachments](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_attachments) seems to use Tika to index PDF documents, you can start looking at its code.